# M-Tron spaceships complete list

Tags: theme

In a old LEGO box lost in my garage I found pieces and instructions of various M-Tron models:

- 6811 Pulsar Charger
- 6833 Beacon Tracer
- 6877 Vector Detector
- 6896 Celestial Forager
- 6923 Particle Ionizer
- 6596 Stellar Recon Voyager

In there any place where I can found the complete list of M-Tron sets? I remember at least a couple more: a big wheeled vehicle (found! 6986 Mega Core Magnetizer) and something else.

Is there any "official list" or something similar?
Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BrickSet has [a list of items in the Space: M-Tron theme](https://brickset.com/sets/theme-space/subtheme-m-tron).